# command substitution: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `conda'

Tags: bash, anaconda

I am trying to get the anaconda version installed and save it in a variable called `CONDA_VERSION` , I try to do this in bash script using the following:

```
echo "INFO: getting conda version"
CONDA_VERSION=$(print(conda -V))
```

but I get this error:

```
 command substitution: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `conda'
```

Comment: remove the inner braces `( )` and `printf`

Comment: What is `print` here? `conda_version=$(conda -V)` itself suffices.

Comment: (all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself; variables defined by application code should use lower-case characters by POSIX-specified convention; relevant standard at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, should be read keeping in mind that setting a regular shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable).